# How to use in laravel 5.4 local scope in a relation call?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I use in my project laravel 5.4 and have 2 models, first model is Group and second model ist Ticket.

In model Group I have following relation:

```
public function tickets() {
 return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Ticket', 'group_id');
}
```

In table tickets (model Ticket) I have a bool field called "open", and the local scope:

```
public function scopeOpen($query) {
   return $query->where('open', 1);
}
```

How can I filter now by using this relation like: `$group->tickets->open`, do I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a relation as such:

```
public function ticketsOpen()
{
   return $this->tickets()->open();
}
```

and then use it as follows:

```
$group->ticketsOpen;
```

Answer (score 1):

A few ways you can do this.

Add this relation to the Group model

```
public function openTickets()
{
    return $this->tickets()->open();
}
```

Access the open tickets like so

```
$group->openTickets
```

---

Or filter the tickets when fetching the results.

```
$group = Group::with(['tickets' => function ($query) {
    $query->open();
}])->get();
```

Accessed tickets will have the `open` scope applied.

```
$group->tickets
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Group::with('tickets')->open()->get();
```